# Is it haram to have sex for fun?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife

Is it haram to do sex for fun in marriages? Does that count as zina? I was told it is haram and your only allowed to do sex when wanting a baby.

Comment: No it isn’t as long as it is consensual on both sides and done in marriage

Answer (score 5):

```
 I was told it is haram and your only allowed to do sex when wanting a baby.
```

On the contrary, the default rule about sex between a husband and wife is that it is permissible.

> والذين هم لفروجهم حافظون إلا على أزواجهم أو ما ملكت أيمانهم فإنهم غير ملومين
>
> And they who guard their private parts. Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed
>
> <sup>— [Quran 23:5-7](https://quran.com/23/5-7)</sup>

And there are only certain exceptions where it is temporarily forbidden; such as during menstruation, post-natal bleeding, fasting, ihram, itikaf, zihar.

Intending for a child is not a condition for it being permissible, rather recognised shara'ee  goals also include seeking lawful pleasure, quenching desire, preserving health, defending against haram urges, and fulfilling the right of the spouse to achieve the same.

> كل ما يلهو به الرجل المسلم باطل إلا ... وملاعبته أهله
>
> All idle pastimes that the Muslim man engages in are falsehood, except for ... and his playing with his wife.
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/22/19)</sup>

> قالوا: يا رسول الله، أيأتي أحدنا شهوته ويكون له فيها أجر؟
>
> قال: أرأيتم لو وضعها في حرام أكان عليه فيها وزر؟ فكذلك إذا وضعها في الحلال كان له أجر
>
> They asked: O Messenger of Allah, if one of us fulfills his desire, will he be rewarded for that?
>
> He said: 'Do you not see that if he did it in an unlawful manner, there would be a burden of sin on him for that? Similarly, if he does it in a lawful manner, he will be rewarded for it.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/66)</sup>

> إذا أحدكم أعجبته المرأة، فوقعت في قلبه، فليعمد إلى امرأته فليواقعها، فإن ذلك يرد ما في نفسه
>
> If one of you likes a woman and feels attracted to her, let him go to his
> wife and have intercourse with her, for that will repel what is in his heart.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/12)</sup>

Also note that 'Azl (a form of contraception) is [permissible](https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/161-163), even though it is sex with explicit effort made to avoid conception. And there is sex in paradise which is purely for pleasure and not childbirth.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. In fact, it should be fun. Only two things prohibited, that is to do that when your wife is on menstruation, and to do that through anus. As far as I know, those are the only thing that prohibited.

Comment: And consent on both sides.

Comment: yes, of course, and that